# MySQL "=" behaves like "like" operator when comparing against number inside single quote

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `size_details` WHERE size_details.standard = 20
```

**Results**

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM `size_details` WHERE size_details.standard = '20'
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: the results are correct :-) . in your first sample you compare the string with a number (20). MySQL tried to convert the string to an integer and stops at the first bad char (x). so the compare is true and in the resultset. in the second you compare string with string

Comment: See this demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c4f76df41a78a48dc9db2c9f57b353a)

Comment: @BerndBuffen *MySQL tried to convert the string to an integer and stops at the first bad char (x).* No. Both operands are converted to floating-point before comparing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example the constant you're comparing against is expressed as an integer so MySQL attempts to cast the value from the table to an integer for comparison. It will proceed character by character until it encounters a non-numeric character.

In your example `20x20` will cast to `20` because the conversion stops at `x`. This passes the comparison.

In your second example both parts of the comparison are strings and `'20x20'` is not equal to `'20'` so the comparison fails.

Comment: *so MySQL attempts to cast the value from the table **to an integer** for comparison.* No. Both operands are converted to floating-point (real) before comparing. See [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) - the most last rule is applied.

Comment: @akina thanks for the link. I spent about 20 minutes hunting for that. Clearly my Google-foo was lacking today.